# Custom Editor not passing parameters to Custom SaveAction

Tags: xaml, sitecore

I've got a problem that has been anoying me for hours!

I have created a custom save action and a custom editor: by following this tutorial: http://toadcode.blogspot.dk/2013/03/create-web-forms-for-marketers-custom.html

In my OnOK method of the backend code for the custom editor field, i have this:

```csharp
protected override void OnOK(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

    SheerResponse.SetDialogValue(
        ParametersUtil.NameValueCollectionToXml(new NameValueCollection() 
    { 
        {"TargetLogId", "SomeID" }
    }));
    base.OnOK(sender, args);

}
```

and in my save action:

```csharp
    public string TargetLogId { get; set; }        

    public override void Execute(Sitecore.Data.ID formid, Sitecore.Form.Core.Client.Data.Submit.AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {
        /*
        code
        */
    }
```

Problem is TargetLogId is always null in my Save Action, instead of the expected "SomeID" value. What am i doing wrong?

Edit:
XAML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <control xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense"
     xmlns:def="Definition">
     <SaveFormToCsvSettings>
      <FormDialog ID="Dialog" Icon="Applications/32x32/gear.png">
      <CodeBeside     Type="xxx.yyy.SitecoreDialogs.ChooseTargetItem,xxx.yyy.SitecoreDialogs"/>



      <Combobox ID="AvailableTargetLogs"></Combobox>

    </FormDialog>
  </SaveFormToCsvSettings>
</control>
```

In the custom save action item i am pointing to the Save Actions class and assembly.

The editor shows up fine when i click edit on the save action.. and the SheerResponse.SetDialogValue method is fired. Is this really the right way to go?

Comment: Have you been able to confirm the Sitecore set-up has been completed correctly and you're able to debug and see "SomeID" going into TargetLogId?

Comment: I am able to set a breakpoint in the OnOk method  and see that NameValueCollectionToXml does indeed create valid XML. So the code does execute if that is what you are asking

Comment: This is really getting on me. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your XAML to post? Additionally have you checked in the data argument see what is contained there?

Comment: I posted the XAML.. yes the data argument just contains the ID of the form that executed the Save Action

Comment: One difference I can see in the XAML to the example is that the ID of the Edit tag, the ComboBox in yours, is the same name as the property defined and passed to the NameValueCollection. Try changing the XAML tag to TargetLogId